# Custom Google maps search

Tags: php, google-maps

I need to search data from my db and show it in Google Maps.
For instance, when I search hotel in Rome, it will be display ONLY the hotel in Rome (or near) and in my db.
I use PHP to get data from db.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the full text search on your part, and then use the coordinates of your stored element to display it in google map.

Comment: So, if i understand u, i do a simple search, so i show my elements (marker) in maps. But how can i get only the near elements ?
Can i load my results on maps and then search in these results ?